# placeholder fully not visible for input type number on firefox when using certain font family

Tags: css, firefox, placeholder, firefox-quantum

`input[type="number"]` field does not showing the placeholder text in latest firefox for certain font family like `font-family: 'Open Sans';`. The current version is **Firefox Quantum 57.0.2 (64-bit)**

**Still don't know some font family have no such issue**

Please check on the demo link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpqzEB

[image]

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<input type="text" placeholder="Text field" />
<hr>
<input type="number" placeholder="Number field" />
```

Comment: Did you try using `line-height`?

Comment: @Soolie Yes, there is `line height` in input properties

Comment: I'm on Quantum and it looks fine to me, so maybe it's another style on your page making it break?

Comment: @kauffee000 please check the demo link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpqzEB

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Works fine for me as well.

Comment: A good working example here: https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb. Browsers cover number inputs differently, unfortunately, which is why you're having an issue. CSS Tricks covers some differences here: https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/

Comment: Maybe use box-sizing: initial; ?

Comment: @ElvinMammadov That does break the entire design :-(

Comment: Looks like others have similar issue --> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23209

Answer (score 1):

It's your border-box property.

I'm not sure why it's happening on CodePen because it looks fine on JSBin and here on StackOverflow in the snippet you posted. Maybe it's CodePen not working great with Quantum.

Anyway, here's what's happening:

The border-box property will make it so the padding and border are included in total width and height of the element ([w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)).

Your input height is set to 40px. That 40px has to include the border, padding-top, padding-bottom, and the height of the element itself. Your line-height is also set to 40px. Your padding styles (you have two rules set, so it picks up the second one) is `padding: .5rem 1rem;`.

There isn't enough room for the input text in these 40 allocated pixels with.
[image]

Issue: **40px line height + top padding + bottom padding > 40px**

As for a fix, I'm assuming you want to keep your padding and have your inputs the same size. You may need to make your font size smaller or make your inputs larger. 40px isn't enough for the padding and a 40px line height. Or you can remove that border-box property.

It kinda looks to me that the difference between this property on Chrome and on Firefox is that Chrome is ignoring the line-height. In this screenshot on Chrome, the height of the input is 22px, even though your line-height is 22px.

[image]

Comment: Here's a jsbin on Quantum just to show that it works on here and not Codepen. http://jsbin.com/wawohubobo/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the issue is that font-size is in excess of the number input controls.

Your example can be fixed preciesely by using:

```
padding: 0.46rem 1rem;
```

---

### EXPLAINED

When padding is applied to a number type input the padding is applied to the boundaries of the box in the normal way however in some browsers cropping occurs relative to the amount of padding applied.

The cropping effect is calculated from the inside boundaries of the input arrow controls.

[image]

The cropping only affects placeholders because they are behind the input layer and become hidden when the interior boundaries of the input field are moved to cover it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpZPKd

There are various ways to avoid this however my recommendation is to avoid padding on input elements and to use alternate methods to create the desired effect.

---

### Be an illusionist

Personally I don't see any reason to use vertical padding inside input fields. `Line-height` does a better job.

If you can't make the browsers do what you want make the user think the browser is doing what you want!

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.Wrap{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
.Wrap input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="Wrap"><input type="text" placeholder="Text field" /></div>
<hr>
<div class="Wrap"><input type="number" placeholder="Number field" /></div>
```

**Codepen example**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaNOdo

Comment: changing padding effecting the design. All the input fields are working fine except `input[type="number"]`. at the same time there is no such issue with other fonts :-)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I change to height of your input field to anything above 40px it seems to work. Try this:

```
input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 41px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';

    background-clip:content-box;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

I can't see why this fixes it though.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

You use two times PADDING in your css input declaration...

Just remove the first one : `padding: 0 10px;`

And keep :  `padding: .5rem 1rem;`

```css
body{
  padding: 2rem;
}
input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    background-clip:content-box;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

input[type="number"] {
    
    // line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Text field" />
<hr>
<input type="number" placeholder="Number field" />
```

Comment: Using `padding` works fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox. I think the OP is trying to address the difference